# Define XML as JAX-WS input parameter

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I need to implement Java SOAP JAX-WS Web service. Web Service client sends XML file to the Web Service. Then need to Process received XML content finally then return processed content in XML format to the WS Client.

This is my Sample XML that has simple three tags.

```
    <uild>898999999</uild>
    <customer>cName XXX</cusoter>
    <profileId>TEST/TKTG MR</profileId>
```

I declared my Web Service method as below.
    RequestXmlDTO has fields in XML. 
    ProcessedResponseDTO has XML fields need as an output. I add these two as complex Type.

```
@WebService
public class WebService {

    @WebMethod
    public ProcessedResponseDTO getCustomerDetails(RequestXmlDTO requestXml){

    }
```

Question - Is this the recommended & best way to cater this scenario ?

Comment: Seems okay. Did you try compiling your service with e.g. Apache CXF's java2wsdl (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-wsdl.html)? That should relieve you from writing any xsd or wsdl manually.

Comment: I am using CXF2.2.6. What is the class I should use to generate WSDL. Is it https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/tools/java2wsdl/processor/JavaToWSDLProcessor.html

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used CXF in a while. It's actually preferable to use [java2ws](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-ws.html) in the newer versions instead of `java2wsdl`. You use the class that's annotated with `@WebService`, i.e. the [Web Service Endpoint Implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbos/index.html) to generate the WSDL and the stubs. So, a very basic example command could be `java2ws org.my.package.WebService`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide the strategy "Cotract First" or "Code First" 
If you decide to go ahead with

"Contract First" Define your schema as the first step. Then generate JAXB objects may be

using a tool. Similar to the class you have mentioned declare the web service signature in a java

interface. Use the method signature to generate the WSDL using (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-wsdl.html) .

Use this WSDL to generate server stubs. You may use ANT target like

```
<target name="wsdl2Java" >          
            <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
                <arg value="-d"/>
                <arg value="modules/deployments/src/java"/>
                <arg value="-p"/>
                <arg value="com.solution.webservices.version1.jaxb"/>
                <arg value="-ant"/>
                <arg value="-impl"/>
                <arg value="-server"/>              
                <arg value="path/wsdl/sample.wsdl"/>
                <classpath>
                    <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
                </classpath>
            </java>
    </target>
```